# "Graphics gallery" or "graphic gallery"

Tags: word-choice

Is the term *graphics gallery* or *graphic gallery* more appropriate for a gallery that contains images?

*Graphics gallery* sounds more right. However, I would choose *photo gallery* over *photos gallery* and *image gallery* over *images gallery*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a gallery of graphics, I'd call it a *graphics gallery*.

If it's a gallery that is graphic in nature, it's a *graphic gallery*.

*Graphic* can be a noun or an adjective, but used with *gallery* it sounds like an adjective. Using *graphics*, which can only be interpreted as a noun, eliminates the ambiguity.

Comment: To be clear, what is your stand on "image gallery" vs "images gallery" ?

Comment: @Pacerier, that's a great point... I'll clarify the post. To answer the question, *image* isn't an adjective, so there's no room for confusion.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification =D Btw grammatically speaking "images gallery" is acceptable as well ? Or is "image gallery" the only grammatically correct one here

Comment: I'll reverse my original opinion and say that usually, you'd just use a singular noun: *image gallery*, *photo gallery*, *sculpture gallery*. As @BarrieEngland points out, though, the plural *graphics* is usually used when a noun is required. Ambiguity happens when the word can be an adjective or "noun adjunct". If you went to a *football gallery* you'd probably expect images and sculptures related to the sport, not a room full of footballs. I'd call the latter a *gallery of footballs*.

Answer (score 3):

The OED records ‘graphic’ only in the plural when used to mean ‘an example of the graphic arts or of graphic design’.  You can use it adjectivally to describe what the gallery contains.